# Android: textViews now visible in activity?

Tags: android, xml, android-activity

Within my Android Activity I am attempting to add two textviews at the bottom of the screen, not within the table.

However, within my activity they are not visible. They are definitely declared correctly in the corresponding activty. What is the error within my XML code below?

**XML code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout03"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow04"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/Spinner01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </Spinner>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow05"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="10sp" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mainTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="20sp"
            android:text="Memory Game"
            android:textColor="#EEFFAA"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:visibility="visible" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myWebSite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:bufferType="normal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="http://www.aviyehuda.com"
            android:textColor="#FFEEAA"
            android:typeface="normal" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/card1" >
            </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSeeMeditation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" "
        android:textSize="25dp" 
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"/>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSeeAttention"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" "
        android:textSize="25dp" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

EDIT (2nd attempt-still not visible)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp" >

<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout03"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow04"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/Spinner01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </Spinner>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow05"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="10sp" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mainTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="20sp"
            android:text="Memory Game"
            android:textColor="#EEFFAA"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:visibility="visible" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myWebSite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:bufferType="normal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="http://www.aviyehuda.com"
            android:textColor="#FFEEAA"
            android:typeface="normal" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/card1" >
            </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp" >


<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSeeMeditation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" "
        android:textSize="25dp" 
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"/>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSeeAttention"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" "
        android:textSize="25dp" />
    </LinearLayout> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you last two textview with ids tvSeeMeditation and tvSeeAttention respectively are defined in the table layout

Comment: OK, how do I solve this to make them visible on screen?

Comment: define your last two textviews outside tablelayout and put this tablelayout in relative layout or linear layout

Comment: Just a tip: don't use fill_parent it was fixed a while ago with match_parent, and for showing them try write some text to see if it shows.

Comment: Can you please see my edit to the question.I attempted to solve the problem by doing what was suggested but it isnt working

Comment: Put something in `text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are visible add some text to them and you will see them in your UI. Also in order to add some UI element to bottom of the screen you should use something like this;

```
<RelativeLayout >

    <TableLayout></TableLayout>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSeeAttention"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=" "
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

else your textviews will be at the end of your table not at the bottom of the screen.

**EDIT:** Your table layout;

[image]

after changing it as android:layout_height="wrap_content"

[image]

Comment: There several mistakes in your edit. First your table view height is already filling the screen so there is place for your second linear layout. You need to make it android:layout_height="wrap_content". Secondly even if you shorten your tableview second linearlayout will be attached to at the bottom of the tableview. In order to put something at the bottom of the screen you need to use Relative Layout or you need create something tricky by your own. You can give margin_top to your linear layout but it wont work for every screen size.

Comment: I have made the edits you suggested, it partially solves the issue however the two textviews are now on top of one another? How can I solve this? You help is very appreciated!

Comment: I assume that you gave android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" to textviews, but you need to give that parameter to linearlayout which is containin the textviews.

Comment: Actually i got it sorted by using: android:layout_below="@+id/tvSeeMeditationMemory"

Comment: Im not sure what u mean sorry?

Comment: In order to understand the problem you need to edit your question and post the last version of your layout code.

Answer (score 0):

Give some value of  `android:text` to every `textview` in yor `xml` file(say it anything like "tv1" and so on) and then check that whether or not they are not placed inside your `table layout`.Because there are `textview`s with empty `android:text` in your file and you may not be able to see there position on the screen

Comment: I have given values to them but I am still unable to see them in my activity?